# Symfony 4.1.4 isSubmitted() doesn't work on rendered form

Tags: php, symfony

So I have this simple form:

```
    class CreditType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('credits', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Product::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('product')
                          ->orderBy('product.amount');
            },
            'expanded' => true,
            'choice_label' => function ($key) {
                return $key->amount.' credits voor maar '.$key->price;
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

which I use in the following Controller:

```
public function credits(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CreditType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        throw new \Exception('It works!');
    }
    return $this->render(
        'credits/credits_widget.html.twig',
        [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

And use this in my XXX.html.twig

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\DetailsController:credits')) }}
```

I have been working with symfony for 4 weeks now so not that long.

I want to call some functions when the form is submitted only nothing that I place in the if statement is working, it doesn't throw any exception at the moment. Am I not seeing something or is it not possible to do this when I render a form?

EDIT: 
my credits_widget.html.twig

```
{% block credits %}
        {{ form_start(form.credits) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.credits) }}

        {% if app.user %}
            <button type="submit">Koop nu!</button>
        {% else %}
            <a href="#login-form"><button type="button">Login en koop</button></a>
            <a href="{{ path('user_registration') }}"><button type="button">Registreer en koop</button></a>
        {% endif %}
        {{ form_end(form.credits) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Symfony version?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this, its in the title now: Symfony 4.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the form is rendered without action and when submitted, it is submitted by default to the root route from which it was rendered. So the credits action is not being called. You should change the action of the form like this:

```
public function credits(Request $request)
{
    // set current url path as form's action 
    $form = $this->createForm(CreditType::class, null, , [
        'action' => $request->getRequestUri()
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        throw new \Exception('It works!');
    }
    return $this->render(
        'credits/credits_widget.html.twig',
        [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

**EDIT**: You are currently rendering subform `form.credits` when you should really render form as it is passed from your controller. Your credits_widget.html.twig template should look like this:

```
{% block credits %}
        {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}

            {% if app.user %}
                <button type="submit">Koop nu!</button>
            {% else %}
                <a href="#login-form"><button type="button">Login en koop</button></a>
                <a href="{{ path('user_registration') }}"><button type="button">Registreer en koop</button></a>
            {% endif %}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Any path that I put in there doesn't work but it also doesn't change, if I put 'method' => 'GET' the form still remains as method="post"

Comment: Maybe you should include also code in credits_widget.html.twig in your answer, so we can check if something in your rendering is wrong. The problem you present doesn't seem logical

Comment: I pasted it in the question, hope this clears things up

Comment: Updated my answer to fix your problem.

Comment: This indeed fixed that I can add actions and a method etc but the exception still doesn't get thrown..

Comment: do you have the proper route('credits') as form action in your html?

Comment: I did not, now it does throw the exception! only thing is that the credits also is a whole separated page. But at least the isSubmitted works!